# Cleaning butyl rubber

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

In almost every butyl rubber product (stopper, gloves, masks) a thin white, powdery spots appear over time. I have tried scraping it, cleaning it with detergent, etc. But it comes back a day or maybe three after cleaning it. What is causing this? Is debris sticking to the rubber? Is the butyl rubber reacting in some way?

Comment: These are made one time use only, Don't use these products again and again. Once used must be discarded, that's what we used to do in our lab.

Comment: @Khan I think he is talking about door stoppers, half face protection masks that with replaceable  filter cartridges, and thick gloves.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this MSDS](http://www.astlettrubber.com/pdf/sr/msds/bk-1675n.pdf), Astlett Rubber, Inc.'s *BUTYL RUBBER BK-1675N* product contains multiple stabilizers and antiaglomerates, each of which is described as a white powder. I suspect it is the leaching or other means of migration of these stabilizer's to the rubber surface that causes the white spots. The following is an excerpt from the above MSDS:

> **Butyl rubber** contains moisture, stabilizer (Agidol-2 or Irganox-1010)
>   and antiaglomerate (calcium stearate or zinc stearate). Stabilizer and
>   antiaglomerate are not discharged into the atmosphere during
>   processing butyl rubber into finished goods.
>
> **Stabilizer Agidol-2** is a white crystalline combustible powder. Flash
>   point in the open crucible is 172°C, ignition point is 208°C, the
>   standard temperature of spontaneous ignition is 352°C. Agidol-2 is
>   permitted for use as a stabilizer of rubber that is used in food
>   industry, in water  pipelines, and children toys production.
>
> **Stabilizer Irganox-1010** is white crystalline combustible powder.
>   Ignition point is 288°C. Meets all requirements for use as a
>   stabilizer in rubber th at is used in medicine.
>
> **Zinc Stearate** is white crystalline powder or paste. The standard
>   temperature of spontaneous ignition is 900°C. Maximum permissible
>   concentration in work area is 4 mg/m3.
>
> **Calcium Stearate** is a white powder. The standard temperature of
>   spontaneous ignition is 560°C. Maximum permissible concentration in
>   work area  is 10mg/m3.